# PATH_MANIPULATION Coverity issue in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to resolve path_manipulation coverity issue reported in below code. Any suggestions to
resolve this issue?

```
fileName = moment(new Date()).format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')
fileOriginalName = `sample_${fileName}`
dirPath = 'DIR/TEST/'
sanitizedFileName = fileOriginalName.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]/g,"")+'.xlsx'
key = path.join(dirPath, sanitizedFileName)
uploadData = { Bucket: process.env.bucketName, body: fileBuffer, key: key}
await uploadToS3(uploadData)
```

Comment: What issue? It looks like you are already sanitizing your filename by removing everything that is not a letter, digit, underscore or minus - so where would there be any possibility for path manipulation left here?

Comment: Not sure why you are even doing that in the first place - you _create_ your filename as `sample_` plus a date in the format `YYYYMMDDHHmmss` appended. So how _could_ any other characters get in there in the first place ...

Answer (score 1):

The PATH_MANIPULATION issue reported by Coverity in your code is related to the use of user-controlled input to construct a file path. In your code, the dirPath variable contains a static value of DIR/TEST/, but the sanitizedFileName variable is constructed using user-controlled input (fileOriginalName). An attacker could potentially manipulate the fileOriginalName input to inject arbitrary characters into the file path, potentially leading to unauthorized file access or other security issues.

To resolve this issue, you should sanitize the fileOriginalName input before using it to construct the file path. In your code, you're already doing this by using the replace method to remove any characters that are not alphanumeric or underscore/dash. However, it's still possible that an attacker could use special characters to construct a path traversal attack.

One way to prevent path traversal attacks is to use a whitelist approach to validate the input. For example, you could define a list of allowed characters for the filename, and only allow input that contains those characters. Here's an example implementation:

```
const allowedChars = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/
fileName = moment(new Date()).format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')
fileOriginalName = `sample_${fileName}`
sanitizedFileName = fileOriginalName.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]/g,"")
if (!allowedChars.test(sanitizedFileName)) {
  throw new Error('Invalid filename')
 }
dirPath = 'DIR/TEST/'
key = path.join(dirPath, sanitizedFileName+'.xlsx')
uploadData = { Bucket: process.env.bucketName, body: fileBuffer, key: key}
await uploadToS3(uploadData)
```

In this implementation, the allowedChars variable defines a regular expression that matches only alphanumeric characters, underscore, and dash. The test method is then used to check whether the sanitized filename contains any characters that are not in this whitelist. If it does, an error is thrown and the code execution stops.

By using a whitelist approach to validate the filename, you can prevent path traversal attacks and ensure that the file path is constructed safely.

Comment: _"but the sanitizedFileName variable is constructed using user-controlled input"_ - not really, unless the user was in control of what date & time it is ... :-)

Comment: is this chat gpt :P?

Comment: Well this is my second account which i dont use anymore. I am trying to get it banned by phrasing my questions in a similar way to chatgpt's. But yes the code snippet is not chatgpt's.

Comment: @cmgchess No. It is not from chat gpt.